# How to stress test comet server?

Tags: comet, stress-testing, orbited

I would like to test how many connections it can support.

I am using orbited, specifically the streaming, **not** long polling.

Answer (score 2):

[Webload](http://radview.com) is the thing you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend Jmeter.  It's easy to setup a basic test, and can be incredibly flexible.

Overview: http://jmeter.apache.org/index.html

Manual: http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/index.html